# Where does hard drive save the bad sector count number?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery

I want to repair a hard disk that has ***652*** bad sectors and when I use HDD regenerator, it reports that bad sectors were fixed, but when I try to install Windows or Linux, the hard drive doesn't accept that, so I tried to use a program called Disk. That program reports that nothing happens to the hard drive and it still has 652 bad sectors.

So what can I do, and where exactly does he hard disk save the bad sectors count number?

Comment: It's not clear what you're talking about. What does "the hard doesn't except that" mean? What is the actual problem you're having?

Comment: i am not good in english , but i mean the opposite of refuse

Comment: hard disk dose not except to install windows

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. Do you mean some particular tool is giving you some particular result? You describe what you're doing in very vague terms. For example, you say things like "I try to start my car but it won't start" rather than "I put my key in the ignition and turned it, I heard a groaning sound and the dome light went out". (How far do you get? What precisely goes wrong? What error do you get?)

Comment: Just because you ran this tool does not mean those sectors are not still bad.  If those sectors are located where Windows wants to place files your going to have a problem.  You can't actually "repair" disks with bad sectors.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - He means `accept` not `except`

Comment: so what shall i do to fix any bad sectors

Comment: @Ramhound I still don't understand what he means. What does it mean for a disk to "accept" installing Linux or Windows? Does that mean the installer fails? Reports an error?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - He means that Windows and Linux will not install because of the bad sectors.  In other words despite him "fixing" the bad sectors Windows and Linux installers still believe there are bad sectors.

Comment: @adam - You don't.  As I indicated you can't actually fix bad sectors.  The sectors are still bad, you have a LOT of bad sectors, the hdd needs to be replaced.  Any data on the hdd WILL be lost eventually.

Comment: yes installation failed , but when i try to install old ubuntu 12.04 it accept and after installation i trid a program called disk ,that program give me an error with the hard disk with number of bad sectors [652]

Comment: Perhaps you can post a screenshot or a photo..

Comment: Bad sectors are still bad sectors even after you run any disk verification / check tool. However they should be marked as bad so they are not used. This should not affect any os installation.

Comment: Nevertheless, clearly this is a very bad hard drive, and I would not recommend using it all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is bad sectors on a HD there is no much you can really do, because is a physical problem over the disk surface. When one hard disk found those problems (on any system), try to recover the information of that bad sectors , if not possible, the sector is marked like bad and is not used again, reallocating the rest info inside on another place on the HD. All this is transparent for the user. Those programs you use try to make some operations like force the read over that bad sectors, if the HD can "recover them" quitting the bad sector if the read is positive. There is no physical touch between the heads of a HD and the surface, so can't do a physical repair or something similar. When a program use the term "fix" refer to mark those sectors like bad for not be used again.

Anyway a hard disk with several account of bad sectors is a bad signal, not store important files inside, usually appears more bad sectors.

Comment: is there any way to magnet the surface of the hard disk a gain , i heard a bout a machine make re magnet to the surface like its manufacturer

Comment: Usually the bad sectors are bad shutdowns which made the head touch by error the surface, making a physical damage, or simply a degrade from the own material. Even if that machine exist, how much can cost the fixing? How much costs one HD today compared? Perhaps not make sense fix it by the price. If your hd is a Seagate, for example, you can send to manufacturer and they will send you another "refurbished". Anyway , not care about those 652 bad sectors, if your hd is of some TBs , there is not much and you not need care about.

Comment: observe : in poor country nothing called i cant fix some thing , there must be a way , and i am as engineer must find a solution

Comment: This answer makes a good point but the grammar makes it basically useless.  Please correct the mistakes so I can up vote it

Comment: @Adam - ***"... magnet the surface of the hard disk again ..."*** - Any write, or erase/format operation will "basically", "re-magnatize" the disk surface in the area that is being written to. If there are "bad" sectors, it means the surface of the disc is in some way damaged, and will not reliably "hold" (retain) the magnetic "charge", even after multiple attempts to erase/write those bad sectors. The damage is physical, and is not something that can be in some way "healed" by some electronic operation.

Comment: @adam - ***"... nothing called i cant fix some thing , there must be a way ..."***. If the surface of the internal disc (platter) is physically damaged, that damage simply can't be repaired. The actual hard disk drive could certainly be repaired by physically replacing the damaged internal disc platter. But this sort of repair requires a laboratory (clean room) environment and would not be economical to do because it would cost way more than a brand new hard drive would cost.

Comment: but could I isolate the damaged part of the platter surface

Answer (score 1):

The best you'll be able to go with this defective hdd is to **zero-fill** it analyzing if it is still usable with the output of **badblocks**.

```
# On Unix
badblocks -s -w -t 0xff /dev/sd?
```

Generally when the number is too large (or growing) the disk will just die if you continue to try it.

Be aware that hard disk fixes is one of the most obscure subjects in computer engineering. If you aren't James Bond of electronics and magnetic disks, dont waste your time.

If you really want to, I have this links to share with you (dont be optmistic):)

- http://www.salvationdata.com/data-recovery-equipment/hd-doctor.htm
- http://forum.hddguru.com/

Comment: nothing called disk die "every thing can be fixed" , i like problem solving any way

Comment: observe : in poor country nothing called i cant fix some thing , there must be a way , and i am as engineer must find a solution

Comment: @Adam there isn't a solution to this problem.

Comment: the hard disk work ok with old OS like ubuntu 12.04 so how it cant be a solution for new OS

Comment: While I like your optimism, sometimes things are just broken and can't be fixed. This has nothing do do with old vs new OS. A hard drive is a complicated piece of equipment and bad sectors (especially the number you are talking about) are usually a symptom of an underlying issue that will only get worse with time. If you put any valuable data on the disk there is a significant risk that you will loose it. While there may be a machine that can repair it (although I'm not aware) the cost would outweigh the cost of a new drive (even in a poor country) and the issue would likely reoccur quickly.

Comment: you cant imagine how poor make people sufere , so in our place some people still use 20 G hard drive [do you see] , by the way can i cut a part of disk i.e make 40 G disk look like 35 G for OS

Comment: Do you have a map of your bad sectors? If they are clustered at the start or the end of the drive, then you could use some clever partitioning to just avoid those areas. Worth a try, definitely.

Comment: If you have a windows boot disk of some sort, try running [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com) on it.

Comment: No @adam, I think you can't. If you could you wont be asking. Disk fixes is one of the most obscure subjects in computer engineering.

Comment: @Adam: I have some burnt matches, spoilt mlik, a molten CPU, a microwaved cd, an accidentally reexposed photograph, a shattered light bulb and some rotten tomatoes. To what poor country do I travel to get these things repaired? I admire your optimism, but the phrase 'broken beyond repair' is not exclusively used in fiction.

Comment: you are right and i will not ask a gain

Comment: Sorry for the expert "knowledge". I like to expand impossible subjects very much, but I do not recommend to anyone trying to learn more of computer science. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the answer, the SMART info is saved in the Service Area (SA) of the hard disk. Basically out of bounds, except for specific tools.

Comment: thats a very helpful answer , but what are those tools ? especially for WD HDD .

Comment: Tools like PC3000, and HD Doctor from Salvation Data. But they cost an arm and a leg.

And even if you bought them, they wouldn't solve the problem. When a hard drives registers a bad sector, its adress is flagged and that happens because de magnetic media in that certain area can not be trusted to hold data.

With these tools, you could simply erase the SMART data, something that would destroy these flags, but doing that 101% of the times **will brick the drive.**